# Bootstrap modal opens on background (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have modal that I open from the table, that in the material tab

Here is Modal HTML

```
    <div
    bsModal
    #createOrEditModal="bs-modal"
    class="modal fade"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="createOrEditModal"
    aria-hidden="true"

>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form
                *ngIf="active"
                #landlordPropertyPortfolioForm="ngForm"
                novalidate
                (ngSubmit)="saveWithReason()"
                autocomplete="off"
            >
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        <span *ngIf="landlordPropertyPortfolio.id">{{ l("EditLandlordPropertyPortfolio") }}</span>
                        <span *ngIf="!landlordPropertyPortfolio.id">{{ l("CreateNewLandlordPropertyPortfolio") }}</span>
                    </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <div *ngIf="!isNew" class="form-group">
                        <label for="LandlordPropertyPortfolio_Name">{{ l("Id") }}</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="LandlordPropertyPortfolio_Id"
                            class="form-control"
                            [(ngModel)]="landlordPropertyPortfolio.id"
                            name="Id"
                            readonly
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="LandlordPropertyPortfolio_Name">{{ l("Name") }}</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="LandlordPropertyPortfolio_Name"
                            class="form-control"
                            [(ngModel)]="landlordPropertyPortfolio.name"
                            name="Name"
                            maxlength="0"
                            maxlength="255"
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button [disabled]="saving" type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="close()">
                        {{ l("Cancel") }}
                    </button>
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-primary blue"
                        [disabled]="!landlordPropertyPortfolioForm.form.valid"
                        [buttonBusy]="saving"
                        [busyText]="l('SavingWithThreeDot')"
                    >
                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i> <span>{{ l("Save") }}</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<change-reason-modal
    #changeReasonModal
    [dtoModel]="landlordPropertyPortfolio"
    (save)="save()"
    (close)="onChangeReasonModalClose()"
>
</change-reason-modal>
```

It opens from component where I have tabs

Here is the code of a generic component, where I have tabs

```
 <div *ngIf="tabTemplates" class="row-fluid align-items-center margin-top-20 w-100">
                <mat-tab-group style="width: 100%;">
                    <mat-tab *ngFor="let tabTemplate of tabTemplates" label="{{ tabTemplate.title }}">
                        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tabTemplate.template"></ng-container>
                    </mat-tab>
                </mat-tab-group>
                <!-- <tabset class="tab-container tabbable-line">
                    <tab *ngFor="let tabTemplate of tabTemplates" heading="{{ tabTemplate.title }}"
                        customClass="m-tabs__item">
                        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tabTemplate.template"></ng-container>
                    </tab>
                </tabset> -->
            </div>
```

I using angular material tabs now, when I was using tabset (commented code), all was okay, now I have this.

[image]

I cannot click modal, how I can make it not background?

Comment: Does the modal have the highest z-index?

Comment: I tried to add style like `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="z-index: 999999999">` , but it not helps @Rajat

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example on Stackblitz?

Comment: I know this is not the best solution but it will work. You need to remove the top header section class (which is blocking the header on the page) on the model dialog show and again need to add that class back to the header section on dialog hide. Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: I think problem is on backdrop of modal @SainPradeep

Comment: Nope, this is part of very complex stuff @Rajat

Comment: why don't use mat dialog instead of bootstrap modal?

Comment: Because we use bootstrap modal over the system, and we want to stay at it @HienNguyen

Comment: Did you add the component of the modal to the `entryComponents` of your module?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have figured out the solution yet.
I had exactly same issue and I found out that the issue is not about the z-index of modal.

This is caused by the z-index of mat-tab-body-active is 1 which makes the entire content of tab body under the modal backdrop which the z-index = 1040.

I added the following CSS for the component that contains the mat-tab component to override the mat-tab-body-active z-index when the modal is opened like this:

```
::ng-deep .my-component-wrapper.modalOpened {
    .mat-tab-body-active {
        z-index: auto !important;
    }
}
```